# How do I make 2 picturebox match using if statememts for a memory card game? (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a memory matching game, those are the images and their tag.

```
  private void Fruits_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countDown1.Start();
        countDown5.Start();

        picApple.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
        wrdApple.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdApple;
        picBanana.Image = Properties.Resources.banana;
        wrdbanana.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdBanana;
        picKiwi.Image = Properties.Resources.kiwi;
        wrdKiwi.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdKiwi;
        picOrange.Image = Properties.Resources.orange;
        wrdOrange.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdOrange;
        picPineapple.Image = Properties.Resources.pineapple;
        wrdPineapple.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdPineapple;
        picStrawberry.Image = Properties.Resources.strawberry;
        wrdStrawberry.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdStrawberry;
        picBlackberry.Image = Properties.Resources.blackberry;
        wrdblackberry.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdBlackberry;
        picMango.Image = Properties.Resources.mango;
        wrdMango.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdMango;

        picApple.Tag = "apple";
        wrdApple.Tag = "apple";
        picBanana.Tag = "banana";
        wrdbanana.Tag = "banana";
        picKiwi.Tag = "kiwi";
        wrdKiwi.Tag = "kiwi";
        picOrange.Tag = "orange";
        wrdOrange.Tag = "orange";
        picPineapple.Tag = "pineapple";
        wrdPineapple.Tag = "pineapple";
        picStrawberry.Tag = "strawberry";
        wrdStrawberry.Tag = "strawberry";
        picBlackberry.Tag = "blackberry";
        wrdblackberry.Tag = "blackberry";
        picMango.Tag = "mango";
        wrdMango.Tag = "mango";
    }
```

i have 2 images the first is picApple and the other one is wrdApple as you can see in the following code i used the if statement but when i run the application when I click on the picApple it become immediately invisible together with wrdApple.
what I want is to let the user see the first image first and then see the other image if they are a match they become invisible if they do not match then they should be covered again.
any idea on how to do that please?
this is the code for the picturebox

```
     private void picApple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picApple.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
        if ((string)picApple.Tag == (string)wrdApple.Tag)
        {
            picApple.Visible = false;
            wrdApple.Visible = false;
        }
        else if ((string)picApple.Tag != (string)wrdApple.Tag)
        {
            picApple.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
            wrdApple.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdApple;
        }


    }

    private void wrdApple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wrdApple.Image = Properties.Resources.wrdApple;
        if ((string)wrdApple.Tag == (string)picApple.Tag)
        {
            picApple.Visible = false;
            wrdApple.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Is it memory a card game?

Comment: @Orwel yes it is

Comment: The player have to select two cards. You need memorize the first selected card and compare with the second card.

Comment: but how do i memorise it, sorry still new to coding.

Comment: Put it in a class level variable string `lastClickedImage` = "";

Comment: You can make a single generic event handler for an image being clicked. In the class store the last image clicked from the sender parameter and compare the current images tag to that objects tag, if they match then make them both invisible. You also need to have a class level variable to hold if it is the first turn or second, a bool would do this and just inverse it at the end of the event handler. If I have time or you need further explanation, I'll try to code something up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assumes that you want to show the second image for a period of time and also that similar cards use the same image but here it is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Timer _imageTimer;
    private bool _firstClick;
    private PictureBox _firstPictureBoxClicked;
    private PictureBox _secondPictureBoxClicked;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _firstClick = true;
        _imageTimer = new Timer(5000);
        _imageTimer.Elapsed += ImageTimerOnElapsed;
    }

    private void ImageTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _imageTimer.Stop();

        _firstPictureBoxClicked.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { _firstPictureBoxClicked.Visible = false; });
        _secondPictureBoxClicked.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { _secondPictureBoxClicked.Visible = false; });
    }

    private void Picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_firstClick)
        {
            _firstPictureBoxClicked = (PictureBox) sender;
            ShowImage(_firstPictureBoxClicked);
        }
        else
        {
            if (((PictureBox) sender).Tag == _firstPictureBoxClicked.Tag)
            {
                _secondPictureBoxClicked = (PictureBox)sender;
                ShowImage(_secondPictureBoxClicked);
                _imageTimer.Start();

            }
            else
            {
                RemoveImage(_firstPictureBoxClicked);
            }
        }

        _firstClick = !_firstClick;
    }

    private void ShowImage(PictureBox pictureBox)
    {
        switch (pictureBox.Tag)
        {
            case "apple":
                pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
                break;
            case "banana":
                pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.banana;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void RemoveImage(PictureBox pictureBox)
    {
        pictureBox.Image = null;
    }
}
```

It's all done inside of the Main Form, but you can split out the logic if needed. I also used PictureBox controls for this, not sure what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Winform, but the logic will be :

```
public class GameWindows
{
    private Image _firstSelected = null;

    private void Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedImage = (Image)sender;
        if(_firstSelected == null)
        {
            //First selection
            _firstSelected = selectedImage;
            ApplySeletedEffect(selectedImage);
        }
        else
        {
            //Second selection
            if ((string)selectedImage.Tag == (string)_firstSelected.Tag)
            {
                selectedImage.Visible = false;
                _firstSelected.Visible = false;
            }
            RemoveSeletedEffect(_firstSelected);
            _firstSelected = null;
        }
    }
}
```

When the player click on a image, call the `Image_Click` method. `ApplySeletedEffect` will be Winform effect to show the image is selected and `RemoveSeletedEffect` to remove this effect.

First, you can try without the selected effect.